# FatFree routing not working in production

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have an application with many routing paths as follows-

```
F3::route('GET /', 'Main->get_front_page');
F3::route('GET /login/check_for_login', 'Login->check_for_login');
```

The first route is matching properly. However, the second route is not matching and I am getting a 404. Infact, any route after the first one are not matching.

To make matters more complicated, all the routes are working on my local machine.

Comment: Are you using it in a subdirectory or as your main site?

Comment: I am using it as a subdirectory. However, I solved the problem. My rewrite_mod wasnt working properly. The command en2mod doesnt work. One has to change the AllowOverride manually. I forgot that I had done that on my localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your apache .htaccess file. Especially the `RewriteBase` url. I often tend to forget this one :)

Comment: My .htaccess file looks like this- RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L, QSA]

I am also using the same .htaccess file on my localhost.

Comment: I find this error in the error.log - [Mon Mar 19 12:23:56 2012] [error] [client 122.169.95.17] File does not exist: /var/www/login, referer: http://db.educateglobal.org/

I don't understand what this means? Why is it looking for such a file?

Answer (score 0):

For Shared Hosting , the fatfree framework deployment won't work like in local server. So you need to create a .htaccess file

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

create an .htaccess file using the above code and place the file in the root of your fat free framework project. I tried this and works well.