# Fatfree framework route not found

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I am using the fatfree framework and it now happened several times that suddenly a route is not found anymore. Calling the route will result in a 404. If I rename the route without doing any additional changes it is being found again. 
There are no concurrent routes as I am just using simple ones such as:

```
$f3->route('GET|POST /test',
    function($f3) use ($db){ ... });
```

Calling /test will result in a 404. Emptying browser cache or using a different browser does not help. If I change the code to e.g.:

```
$f3->route('GET|POST /test2',
    function($f3) use ($db){ ... });
```

It will be working fine using /test2 .

It worries me a lot that this is happening totally at random and that I have not found any way to fix the old route other than to rename it.

Is it possible to clear a routing related cache of f3 or similar which might solve the problem?

Comment: Routing is not cached but HTTP responses are. You can make sure that cache is disabled by setting the `CACHE` variable to FALSE. Apart from that, can you clarify if this behaviour impacts all routes or only those mapped to an anonymous function. Also make sure that you're using the [latest dev](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/tree/dev) version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have now downloaded and updated to the latest dev version, but still get the same problem. I have set cache to false using $f3->set('CACHE',FALSE); in the index.php and also I have used $f3->clear('CACHE'); as an additional possiblity. Unfortunately I still get the same error. After renaming my route from /test2 to /test , /test still gives me a 404 and /test2 is still reachable. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: If you're using APC, follow instructions given by @ikkez. Otherwise, since this looks like a bug, I'd advise you to post it on the dedicated [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework/) in order to get this sorted out.

Comment: Its because of htaccess. you can find the answer using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769665/fatfree-routing-not-working-in-production?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If your server uses APC Cache, a simple $f3->clear('CACHE'); might be not enough, because it only clears the framework related stuff... The code from index.php and others could still remain in the APC opcache, that could lead to your described problems... Try to clear the whole cache of APC or whatever cache engine you are using... Here an example of how to do it in APC:

http://kaspars.net/blog/web-development/standalone-script-for-clearing-apc-cache